# Retrieve Many to Many relationship data in blade file

Tags: php, laravel, many-to-many, fetch

I have two models **Subject** and **Stream**.
here
Subject belongsToMany Stream and
Stream hasMany Subject 
is the relation.

How can I load the content of Stream in Subject.

**Subject.php**

```
<?php
```

namespace App\Model\Admin;

use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;

class Subject extends Model
{
    protected $guarded = [];

```
public function streams()
{
    return $this->belongsToMany(Stream::class);
}

public function chapters()
{
    return $this->hasMany(Chapter::class);
}
```

}
?>

**Stream.php**

```
<?php
```

namespace App\Model\Admin;

use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;

class Stream extends Model
{
    protected $guarded = [];

```
public function faculty()
{
    return $this->belongsTo(Faculty::class);
}

public function subjects()
{
    return $this->hasMany(Subject::class);
}
```

}

```
?>
```

**My attempt:**

```
 @if (!empty($subject))
                        @foreach ($subject as $key => $subjects)
                        <tr>
                            <td>
                                {{ $key + 1 }}
                            </td>
                            <td>
                                {{$subjects->title}}
                            </td>

                            @foreach($subjects->streams as $item)
                            <td>
                                {{ $item->name}}
                            </td>
                            @endforeach

                            <td>
                                {{$subjects->description}}
                            </td>


@endforeach
@endif
```

**But it gives the error:**

SQLSTATE[42S02]: Base table or view not found: 1146 Table 'pu_notes_db.stream_subject' doesn't exist (SQL: select `streams`.*, `stream_subject`.`subject_id` as `pivot_subject_id`, `stream_subject`.`stream_id` as `pivot_stream_id` from `streams` inner join `stream_subject` on `streams`.`id` = `stream_subject`.`stream_id` where `stream_subject`.`subject_id` = 1)

I have migrated all the tables.
Googled the problem but didnt find the convincing solution.
please Help.

Comment: Can you post then content of Subject and Stream models, especially where you defined the model relationships?

Comment: Please share your eloquent relation

Comment: It seems your relation is wrong

Comment: I have also added the models so that relations can be seen